# Azure Logic Apps Workflow

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus

I don't know why my workflow doesn't run when my logic app is in enable, I don't see the debug with the time spent on each task, thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***First you need to send a message in the queue like below:***

[image]

***Then if you run you will get the message like below:***

[image]

***Then if you press on the succeded message then you will get the details:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and precise explanations, I appreciate your help